# Listen to messages from various texting applications

Tags: java, android, facebook, twitter

Is there any way for android to listen to facebook or twitter messages (maybe whatsapp or viber or skype messages also ). I would like to know when message from certain application arrives. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

There's no common mechanism these apps have to use to work on Android, so the answer in general is "no" as being notified may be either individual thing ("per app"), or not not easily possible (if possible)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any (known) individual "thing" for any application listed above?

Comment: @FirefoxxPwnass I don't think there is such thing.. I heard about an unofficial API for whatsApp but it seems to be dangerous to handle with it :)